# In TypeScript, I can easily type named arrow function, but how do I do the same thing in function keyword based function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, ecmascript-6

Please see this example:

```
const MyFunction: SomeType<SomeProp> = () => {

}
```

It's easier to type `MyFunction` in a named arrow function, but how do I do the same thing in function keyword based function?

```
function MyFunction() {} // ???
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check it out:

```
const MyFunction: SomeType<SomeProp> = function() {

}
```